# Can you set HttpContext.Current.UserIdentity.Name with reflection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection

I am trying this:

```
typeof(FormsIdentity)
    .GetField("Name", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .SetValue(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity, newUsername);
```

but     `typeof(FormsIdentity).GetField("Name", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)` returns null. What I am trying to do is allow a user to change their username.

Comment: You would be better off following the correct process for setting the `HttpContext` identity.

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong with this:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username,true);
```

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: that's great! but it nukes ticket.UserData

Comment: You can get it before calling and setting again, @dolphonebubleine